# How to delete a word and go into insert mode in Vim?

Tags: vim

In normal mode I can hit <kbd>**`Ctrl`**</kbd> + <kbd>**`E`**</kbd> which deletes the rest of the current word and goes to insert mode.

I want to delete the entire word, regardless of the cursor position (within the word of course).

Answer (score 197, accepted):

You can use "change inner word" by typing "ciw" to delete a word your cursor is on.

The "inner" and "a" commands are great in Vim, also try "ci{" inside a {} block, or "ca{" if you also wish to remove the {} characters too.  To translate these commands to English to remember them better, try: "change inner { block" and "change a { block".

Documentation at http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/motion.html#text-objects

Comment: "caw" can be used in place of "ciw" same functionality.

Comment: Whereas 'caw' and 'ciw' will replace the entire word, simply 'cw' will change from the the current cursor position to the end of the current word.

Comment: I edited the answer from telling about "co{" to "ca{" as reminded by jinxed_coders comment.  My old customization implements "(a) <>" commands as "(o)uter <>" commands.

Comment: `ciw` and `caw` are not exactly the same: `ciw` deletes just the word, `caw` deletes the trailing space as well.

Comment: ciw works great with /something as it then replaces what you searched for, a very common situation in my view. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: **:help objects** in vim to read more about these sorts of selections.

Comment: just FYI, I believe the `a` in `caw` and `ca{` stands for "around"

Answer (score 22):

Answer to your follow-up question: `viwp`

```
v    -> start visual mode
iw   -> select the 'inner word'
p    -> paste - in visual mode it replaces the visually selected text.
```

Comment: How would one do this multiple times in a row? Each time you paste, the buffer fills with the word I pasted over.

Comment: @BenGartner Found this at [Vim Tips wiki](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Replace_a_word_with_yanked_text#Alternate_method): Use `yiw` to copy the current word, place the cursor on the word to replace, use `ciw<C-r>0`. After that you can place the cursor on the next word and use `.` to redo the replacement.

Comment: @BenGartner If all you're trying to do is replace all instances of WORD_A with WORD_B, then you simply use vim's ex mode, `:%s/a/b/g`. `a` can be exact text, or a regular expression, and `b` is what you will replace all matches of `a` with. You can test regexes with vim's `/` mode. Replace `%` with a line number or range if you don't want to substitute on all lines.

Answer (score 8):

For the second question: `bPldw`

This will, in order, take you to the beginning of the current word, insert the default register in front of the cursor, go to the next character (taking you past the end of the text you just inserted), and delete the rest of the word.

Comment: this also deletes the space after the word. Should be `bPlde`.

Answer (score 5):

For the first question, `bcw` also work. It means "`b`ack to the begin of word, `c`hange `w`ord". But I think `ciw` is more memorable, which means "`c`hange `i`nner `w`ord", just only one step.

For the second question about "replace using paste", my solution is `"_diwP`. It `d`elete `i`nner `w`ord to a register you don't care and `p`aste the default register's content. An advantage is that you can paste the default register many times, because it wouldn't be polluted. It's a litte complex so I map it as `nnoremap ,r "_diwP`.

Answer (score 2):

Or, you could perhaps use the key sequence `bdwi` to delete the current word and go into INSERT mode.

Comment: You can use `bcw` to go to the beginning of the current word then change the word, which leaves you insert mode.

Comment: If your cursor is already on the first character of the word, that will end up deleting the previous word.

Comment: @WarrenPena In that case, just use `dwi`. Just be careful that the cops don't notice, as DWI is illegal in most states.