# Efficient way to remove multiple spaces between two words in Vim

Tags: vim

Say I had the following text

```
 word1 word2              word3 word4
```

and the cursor was somewhere between `word2` and `word3`.

#### Question

- What's the quickest way to replace the multiple spaces between `word2` and `word3` with a single space in Vim?

#### Initial thoughts

- `:s/  */ /g`

However, I thought there might be something quicker like `diw` but for spaces.

It would also be good if the strategy also worked when the cursor was on the `w` of `word3` or the `2` or `word2`.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

`ciw` and then escape back to normal mode, although it will only work if you're on a space.

Comment: `ciw-space-esc` 5 key presses; that's great; and perhaps a few additional key presses to move the cursor into the space if required.

Comment: but `ldw` only works when the cursor is in a specific position; I guess `gelldw` would work fairly well from a number of relevant cursor positions.

Comment: Just in the spirit of not executing commands that you don't know, as per [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1379214/1474421), `ciw` stands for "change inner word", and will delete the word that the cursor is currently on & put you into INSERT mode.

Comment: `ciw` removes all spaces between words. The answer should be `ciw<space>`.

Comment: This is what I need. It got to be simpler than repeated perform `x`

Answer (score 36):

This works for me:

`:s/\s\+/ /g`

Comment: Thanks. However, that's 11 key presses two of which include a shift.

Comment: I guess this is the amateur vimgolfer in me coming out. the plus and colon both require shift (at least on my keyboard)

Comment: wow, I way misinterpreted your question. haha, sorry, thanks for taking the time to respond ;)

Comment: This works best as search & replace for multiple "space snails" in the bufffer. Thanks.

Comment: This only works on a single line; not a whole text.

Answer (score 11):

Try replacing all double spaces (repeated zero or more times) with a single space.

```
:s/  \+/ /g
```

Comment: Nice!
I had only to use `\s` instead of ` ` to make it work, on the pattern search, but not on pattern substitution:
`:s/\s\s\+/ /g`

Answer (score 2):

I use (bound to a hotkey)

```
i<enter><esc>kJ
```

`i` - insert mode

`k` - up a line

`J` - join lines together

This works no matter where the cursor is inside the whitespace or on the `w` of `word3`, and puts the cursor on the beginning of the word that just got joined. If you want it to work with the `2` on `word2`, just replace the first `i` with `a`.

Comment: Actually, I think this only works because my Join trims lines before joining. Feel free to ignore this answer then!

Comment: This does not answer the question.

Answer (score 1):

```
%s/\(\w\)\s\+\(\w\)/\1 \2/g
%  - global
s - search
\( - escape (
\w - (any letter, digit)
\) - escape )
\(\w\) - remember letter/digit before space as \1
\s - whitespace
\+ - escape +
\s\+ - 1 or more whitespace space
\(\w\) - remember letter/digit after space(s) as \2
/ - replcae with
\1 - remembered last letter/digit before space
' ' - space character here - single space
\2 - remembered first letter/digit after white space(s).
/ - end of replace
g - globally
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.  The documentation may be useful, but a better approach would be providing a specific solution for the question and including the documentation as well.

Comment: Good answer. %s/\(\S\)\s\+\(\S\)/\1 \2/gc would do the job of finding multiple spaces between words and also symbols (or non-whitespaces)

Answer (score 1):

### For a multi-line text

```
:%s/\s\+/ /g
```

Comment: Would be great if you explained what this does and how it solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I would do this in two steps

1. $  // cursor goes to space at the end of the line
2. dw // deletes whitespaces 
   ( use . to repeat as necessary)

Answer (score 0):

In 3 keystrokes, add this to your `init.vim` (neovim) or `.vimrc` (vim):

```
nnoremap <silent> di<Space> /<Space><Space>diwi<Space><Esc>:noh<CR>
nnoremap <silent> da<Space> /<Space><CR>diw:noh<CR>
```

Now, in NORMAL mode, you can "**d***elete* **i***rrelevant* **space**" to replace by a single space, and "**d***elete* **a***ll* **space**" to remove all spaces.

This applies to the current or next block of spaces. Unfortunately, it cannot be repeated with the dot `.` operator.

Answer (score 0):

If you are editing `dt<nextchar>` on the second space to the right of word2 would work, in this case `dtw`.