# How to replace a single word under cursor?

Tags: vim, replace

How do I replace a word under the cursor in Vim.

So instead of using `dw` then `i` then the word and then `Esc`, is there a simpler combination to replace the word under the cursor?

Answer (score 366, accepted):

```
ciw
```

(change inner word) will change the *whole word* under the cursor. Compare with

```
cw
```

which will only change the word from the *current cursor position*. For more info see [this SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1379198/in-vim-how-do-i-delete-a-word-and-go-into-insert-mode) question/answer.

Comment: How to deal with the situation if the word contains dots or slashes (e.g.  `/usr/bin/bash` or `1222.333`)? It looks like vim interprets `/` and `.` as end of the word and won't select the entire string.

Comment: @AlexanderCska you might want to try `cW` or `ciW` (notice uppercase W)

Answer (score 125):

I often find myself wanting to replace one word with another that I have yanked from elsewhere.  The problem with the other solutions is that if you attempt to change a word, then your next paste will *be* that word that you deleted with `cw`.

Try the following:

```
1 "This first word should overwrite the second"

yiw     yank inner word (copy word under cursor, say "first").
...     Move the cursor to another word (say "second").
viwp    select "second", then replace it with "first".
```

Hope that's what you were looking for.

Comment: It works nicely but only if replacement has to be done `once`. If i have to replace couple of `second' by `first` (in your example),  copied word becomes `second` after the first replacement.

Comment: @ViFI, `viw"0p` instead of just `viwp` would help you if want to paste more than once. Basically, the same as `viwp` but with `"0` before pasting, which won't overwrite the buffer

Answer (score 34):

<kbd>c</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>w</kbd>

```
c   change
iw  inner word
```

This will delete the word under the cursor (even if the cursor is somewhere in the middle of the word) and enter insert mode.

---

Also see Vim's documentation for reference:

```
:help c
:help text-objects
```

Answer (score 23):

If you want to change a word with a previously yanked word, there's another solution to `viwp` (once you have yanked the first word).

`ciw` removes the previous word and puts you in insert mode where it was. But then you can use `ctrl+r, 0` to insert the contents of register 0 (which contain the previously yanked word).

So:

```
yiw
[move to next word]
ciw
ctrl+r
0
```

This works better than `viwp` because after the first usage you can then repeatedly perform the replacement with `.`. It also doesn't switch into visual mode and highlight briefly.

Comment: Not sure what you mean that it does not change modes, opposite seems to be the case, but maybe that's what you wanted, to remain in insert mode. 
But a big advantage is that this (contrary to `viwp`) can be done several times with just one yanking. Thanks!

Comment: Oh you're right, I was thinking of going into visual mode, edited. I didn't realize that was a limitation of `viwp` - even `.` doesn't duplicate it.

Comment: This is by far the best solution when we already have yanked the replacement word.

Comment: This is the answer! Ability to use `.` with this is great!

Answer (score 0):

Try `cw` - as in 'change word'.

Use http://linuxmoz.com/vi-commands-cheat-sheet/ or any other cheat sheet as a reference.

Comment: That works, but it will only amend the characters to the right of the cursor

Comment: This solution was already proposed

Answer (score 0):

To copy word under cursor press: <kbd>b</kbd><kbd>v</kbd><kbd>e</kbd><kbd>y</kbd>

To replace the word under cursor press: <kbd>b</kbd><kbd>v</kbd><kbd>e</kbd><kbd>p</kbd>

Comment: If you need to replace several times, search and replace with confirmation: `:%s!first!second!gc`

Comment: would be nice to provide a description of what each of those do