# How to copy/yank only the current word which has only alphanumeric characters in Vim

Tags: unix, vim, copy

Suppose a file has the text such as

```
Natural
Natural8Language
```

I want the whole word to be yanked/copied with easy key shortcuts

Comment: this can be done by little script. let's say, pressing `X` vim does what you wanted. now your cursor is on `foo_bar`, and pressed `X`, what would happen? nothing yanked? so the `"` register saved your previous yanked text.  you just press X, and don't know what would be yanked, is it a good idea?

Comment: Could you clarify? The whole text means the whole file? Do you mean a *file* contains the text instead of "A word has the text"?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66910215/9384511

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
yiw
```

does what you seem to want with the sample provided. It's a *very* basic command.

Comment: The cursor to moves to the beginning of the word, though. I did not ask for the cursor to move.

Answer (score 2):

Would yanking up to the next word boundary with `yW` (capital W) do what you want?
You can paste the yanked word with `p`. I believe it doesn't get much shorter than that (other than mapping keystrokes).

Comment: Is there a way to yank from current cursor to the end of current word?

Comment: Yes. You can use *any* movement command to yank the moved-over part. Move to end-of-word is `e` or `E`. To yank, `ye` or `yE`.