# Vim command: how to select a word under cursor in normal mode

Tags: vim, macvim, xvim

I'm looking for a Vim command to select a word under cursor in normal mode, like double-clicking by mouse. Does it exist like this?

Comment: @pfnuesel `*` selects the next occurrence of the word under the cursor, because it's a search command, not a select command.

Comment: @DanLowe Yep, you're right, i deleted my comment. But `viw` should do the job.

Comment: Won't that put you in visual mode? Is it even possible to select stuff in normal mode?

Comment: Thanks @pfnuesel and @Matthew-strawbridge for answering my question. The command `viw` is what I was looking for :)

Comment: I mapped `v` to `viw` in normal mode to select a word with one-key typing. It seems it's working well.

Comment: The Vim documentation `:help visual-operators` explains how to select a word `vaw` and an inner word `viw`, as well as  paragraphs and various variations of parenthesis blocks and quoted strings.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66910215/9384511

Answer (score 153, accepted):

You can use `*` and/or `#` to search for the word under the cursor or `viw` to visually select the word under the cursor.

Comment: I know `v` and `w`, but what does `i` do while in visual mode?

Comment: @minitauros `i` stands for inner or inside here. `viw` visually selects the inner word. It will be immediately clear what's meant if you open a document with parentheses.  Then put your cursor anywhere inside the parentheses and type `vi(`. It will select everything inside the parentheses. This also works with quotation marks, e.g. `vi"` or `vi'`. If you want to select the parentheses (or quotation marks) as well, you can use `va(` (or `va"`). But I do not know, what the `a` here stands for. And, of course, you cannot just visually select, but also e.g. delete (`di(`) or yank (`yi(`).

Comment: `a` apparently means "around".

Comment: @pfnuesel If your cursor is in the middle of the word, `vw` selects from the middle to the end of the word, while `viw` selects the whole word even if your cursor is in the middle of the word.

Comment: And `ciw` to clear the word under the cursor and swap into insert mode so you can start typing something to replace it.

Comment: `v + i + {` or `v + i + }` Select content inside `{ }`, `{ }` are not selected. `v + a + {` or `v + a + }` Select content around `{ }`, `{ }` are also selected.

Answer (score 66):

`viw` does a visual select inside the word. Similarly `yiw` copies (yanks) the word.

Answer (score 30):

Personally, I am prefering `vaw`, `yaw` instead of `viw` or `yiw` as `a` indicates around.

On the similar lines. I use

`vat` to select tag.
`va(` or `va{` 
`v%` to select matching closing tag. In some other places `ev%`

It is making more sense to me as the intention is to select the complete word not inside.

At the end, it all comes down to our personal preference.

Comment: `vaw` isn't exactly the same. It also selects leading or trailing whitespace.

Answer (score 6):

To select a word under a cursor I use the combination of `bve`

Be aware though that if the cursor points to a first character you just need `ve` combination.

Answer (score 1):

After using `*`, if you want to use the text in a command you can do the `<C-r> <C-w>` trick too (after pressing `:` or your equivalent).