# what's the difference between command cw and ciw in Vim?

Tags: vim

Here's [a link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14233498/replace-word-under-cursor-vim) I find in stackoverflow about this question.

but I still cannot understand without a specific example about what's the difference between "change inner word" and "change word".

I test these two commands in my vim and finally find no differences ,Please give me an example to help me understand, thank you!

Comment: NB: there is an incipient SE site for [vi/vim knowledge](https://vi.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Here is an example:

```
foo bar baz
    ^
```

Typing cw and ciw will give the same result in this case (with the cursor positioned on the 'b' of 'bar').
Consider this:

```
foo bar baz
     ^
```

`cw` will yield

```
foo b baz
     ^
```

where `ciw` will yield

```
foo  baz
    ^
```

so it changes the whole word, regardless of the cursor position. Very useful, i love this command.
Very useful is also the `caw` (or the `aw`) command:

```
foo bar baz
     ^
-> caw
foo baz
    ^
```

`aw` also contains the space. Try these commands with the `v` (visual) command, to see what they all do. Also, read `motion.txt`, part 6.

Comment: It's very kind of you to provide me so much extra information, thank you so much , I understand it now! It is like a magic!

Answer (score 18):

Above answers addressed **HOW** they behave different, i would like to share some idea on **WHY** they behave different.

First, in vim's world, `w` and `iw` have different semantics and can both be seen as `target`(see below):

- `w` in `cw` refers to a `Motion` Object
- while `iw` in `ciw` refers to a `TextObject`

Secondly, in Vim editing, **Operator** (`c/change` in your case, and `y/yank`, `d/delete`, `=/indenting`, `>/shifting` etc) and **Target** (`w` and `iw` in your case) helps you achieve what you want to do with less keystrokes compared to using `visual selection` + `operator`.

> TextObject defines target range (start and end position).
>
> Motion is essentially used to move cursor, so it only define final-target-position (destination to move).

Some good materials to read:

1. `:h motion.txt` part 4, 5
2. AdvancedTopicTutorial from [atom-vim-mode-plus](https://github.com/t9md/atom-vim-mode-plus/wiki/AdvancedTopicTutorial#what-is-a-target)

Comment: In `ciw` the textobject is `iw` not `w` which stands for **i**nner **w**ord

Comment: your answer make me clearer about how these two commands work, and they seems easy to use, but I never had a thought to find the theory of these commands which seems easy to use before, with your kind help, I think I will learn more about whatever things in the future, not just work! Thank you for all! You inspired me.

Answer (score 5):

```
someword
    ^        (cursor)
```

cw

```
some_
    ^        (cursor)
```

Changes from cursor to end of word. Leaves the start of the word.

---

Compared to

```
someword
    ^        (cursor)
```

ciw

```
_
^            (cursor)
```

Changes the entire word from start to end.

Answer (score 3):

Mind you, `cw` has a bit 'unstandard' behavior by default in that it is behaves exactly like `ce`: It only works up until the end of the current word (like `e`, `ce`, `de`, `ye`) instead of including the whitespace up before the beginning of the next word (like `w`, `dw`, `yw`).

Therefore I recommend adding these mappings to your `vimrc`:

```
" Have `cw` adhere to its actual movement `w`, instead of duplicating `ce`.
nnoremap cw dwi
nnoremap cW dWi
```

and getting used to usually using `ce`.  Typing <kbd>c</kbd><kbd>e</kbd> is actually more efficient and less awkward than <kbd>c</kbd><kbd>w</kbd> *if* you form the habit of pressing the <kbd>e</kbd> with your ring finger instead of middle finger when it comes right after <kbd>c</kbd>.

---

If you prefer to leave `cw` with its default assignment duplicating `ce`, then you can access its 'proper' functionality with an additional keystroke: `dwi` (or `vwc`).

(Mind you, I find `dwi` even more efficient to type than `cw` because of the positions of the keys, in spite of the additional key.)

---

<sub>Explanation of the second mapping: `W` (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>w</kbd>) works on what vim calls "WORDS", which counts every non-blank character, e.g. punctuation, as part of a WORD;  while `w` works on "words", which only consist of uninterrupted sequences of letters, digits and underscores (by default).</sub>